My Blender 4.1 whit error AttributeError: 'bpy.app' object has no attribute 'version_char'
is this :
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 376, in enable
mod = importlib.import_module(module_name)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\python\Lib\importlib_init_.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "", line 1204, in _gcd_import
File "", line 1176, in _find_and_load
File "", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 690, in _load_unlocked
File "", line 940, in exec_module
File "", line 241, in call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\mixamo_rig_init.py", line 47, in 
from . import mixamo_rig
File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\mixamo_rig\mixamo_rig.py", line 6, in 
from .utils import *
File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\mixamo_rig\utils.py", line 8, in 
from .lib.bones_pose import *
File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\mixamo_rig\lib\bones_pose.py", line 3, in 
from .version import *
File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\mixamo_rig\lib\version.py", line 3, in 
class ARP_blender_version:
File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\mixamo_rig\lib\version.py", line 7, in ARP_blender_version
_char = bpy.app.version_char
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'bpy.app' object has no attribute 'version_char'
HELP!!

I gave this question a down-vote. It's unclear and not useful. No context whatsoever is provided and no question is even formed. It's unclear what you are trying to do and what you want to know. You should edit it and formulate a clear specific question providing details about your situation and goals and attempted solutions. You have to use language to communicate. "is this:" and "HELP!!" is not sufficient to form a question or any meaning at all.  See Help center, take the tour maybe.

Hi, Paulo, welcome. It's too much to expect us to reverse-engineer what your problem is, by reading a stack-trace. We  have to deduce that this is a problem with an add-on? And then guess at the context which produced the error.? Please give us a little help, to help you, in plain language.  Furthermore, we are not equipped to debug 3rd-party add-ons. we confine ourselves to the add-ons shipped with the application. For any 3rd-party add-on, you should contact its developers, and community.

If that error comes from the Mixamo addon there's a fixed version which works with Blender 4+ described here.

bpy.app.version_char has been deprecated since v4.0.
https://developer.blender.org/docs/release_notes/4.0/python_api/#blender-application-bpyapp


Realmente, o problema está na incompatibilidade do Blender com o Mixamo, vou verificar o link na reaposta do  John Eason, Agradeço a todos.
